# Add progress bar when image is inverting

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-bitmap

I have this simple code which runs perfect when I press button, it inverts my image view's original image. It takes 3 to 4 seconds to do that. I want to add progress bar in between the task to notify user how can I do that? Where can I add progress bar?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_invert_image);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myIView);

    mImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.myimage);
    invertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.invertButton);

    invertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap image = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap readyImage = invertImage(image);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(readyImage);

        }
    });
}

public Bitmap invertImage(Bitmap original){

    Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), original.getConfig());

    int A, R, G, B, pixelColor;
    int height = original.getHeight();
    int width = original.getWidth();

    for(int x = 0; x < height; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < width; y++){
            pixelColor = original.getPixel(y,x);
            A = Color.alpha(pixelColor);
            R = 255 - Color.red(pixelColor);
            G = 255 - Color.green(pixelColor);
            B = 255 - Color.blue(pixelColor);

            finalBitmap.setPixel(y, x, Color.argb(A,R,G,B));
        }
    }

    return finalBitmap;
}
```

Guidance....

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, setting the progress bar with the increment of your initial for loop as a proportion of the complete loop, in this case x = height.

```
private ProgressBar mProgress; // Note your will need to implement the progress bar.

public Bitmap invertImage(Bitmap original){

    .../...

    while (mProgressStatus < 100) 

        for(int x = 0; x < height; x++){
            mProgressStatus = x/height*100;
            mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
            for(int y = 0; y < width; y++){
            .../...
            finalBitmap.setPixel(y, x, Color.argb(A,R,G,B));
        }
    }

    return finalBitmap; 
}
```

From the [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) docs.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

 private ProgressBar mProgress;
 private int mProgressStatus = 0;

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

     mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 mProgressStatus = doWork();

                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }).start();
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you..here in the begining of ur code it is int i=0; and not x right? as x is already assigned in for loop....

Comment: confused...plus mProgressBarStatus value is also making me confused.. as its equation (height-x) * 100 will make it more than hundred for first value it self...

Comment: its ok. now it seems perfect so I have to initiate status value to 0 and what about that int x=0?

Comment: does not work..added progressbar and just progress bar is running on the image at the launch and when i click the button activity frozes